# Separate comma from list and display in single row in Java

Tags: java, list

I have put key,value in map as,

```
map.put(id,list);
```

id = 5 and

This list contains values such as:

```
       A 
 OR    A,B, 
 OR    A,B,C 
 OR    sometimes no values.
```

I am iterating over map as,

```
     Iterator itr=map.entrySet().iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
        int key =(Integer)me.getKey();
        List li = (List)me.getValue();
        System.out.println(key,li);
      }
```

I want to system.out.println like in single row,

```
5 | A |         (if list contain A)
5 | A | B |     (if list contain A,B)
5 | A | B | C | (if list contain A,B,C)
5               (only 5 if there are no values as A B C)
```

I am not sure how I can remove the commas from the list and display the list values in separate columns in a single row like above?

Comment: Are you building the map yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. You can create a loop that goes through all the elements and appends a '|' in between.
2. You can override the List ToString() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Iterator itr=map.entrySet().iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
        int key =(Integer)me.getKey();
        List myList = (List)me.getValue();
        System.out.println(key+"|"+StringUtils.join(myList.toArray(),'|'));

      }
```